# how to pass a socket connection from one process to another in C++ for windows?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, process

I am trying to pass a socket connection from one process to another process in C++ using Winsock.

I followed the following procedure:

1. a *sender* process, which establishes a socket connection with the *receiver* process and the process whose socket has to be passed (let's call that process *messenger*)
2. In the *sender* process, I copy the socket using `WSADuplicateSocket()` and get a `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` object, which I am sending to the *receiver* process.
3. upon receiving the `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` object, I am using `WSASocket()` to recreate the socket in the *receiver* function, but upon sending the data to the messenger, the following error shows up:

> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

sender side code:

```
WSAPROTOCOL_INFO protocolInfo;
if (WSADuplicateSocket(clientSocket, GetCurrentProcessId(), &protocolInfo) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to duplicate socket handle: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
//now send over protocolInfo to the peer socket

int bytes = send(peer_socket, (char*)&protocolInfo, sizeof(protocolInfo), 0);
```

receiver side code:

```
WSAPROTOCOL_INFO protocolInfo;
int bytes = recv(peer_socket, (char*)&protocolInfo, sizeof(protocolInfo),0);

SOCKET childSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,&protocolInfo, 0, 0);
if (childSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to create child socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
//this if condition did not run
}
```

What is the correct way to get a copy of a handle to a socket from one process to another?

Comment: You need to pass the _target process's_ PID to `WSADuplicateSocket`, not the current process's PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the wrong Process ID to `WSADuplicateSocket()`, per its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketa):

> [in] dwProcessId
>
> Process identifier **of the target process** in which the duplicated socket will be used.

And per [Sharing Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/shared-sockets-2):

> A source process calls `WSADuplicateSocket` to obtain a special `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure **for a target process identifier**.

You are giving `WSADuplicateSocket()` the *sender's* PID, but you need to give it the *receiver's* PID instead.